# Azure DevOps Windows Machine File Copy Task - Delete Specific Files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps [Windows Machine File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/windows-machine-file-copy?view=azure-devops) task that is deploying a build artifact to a remote server. I would like to be able to clean the target directory ***excluding*** specific files/folders. My use case is that my app generates logging information that I don't want wiped on redeploy.

The Windows Machine File Copy task only seems to contain a checkbox option for "clean." I'd love to be able to use something like the [Delete Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops) minimatch patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd love to be able to use something like the Delete Files task minimatch patterns.

If the files you want to delete are located on remote machine, you could use **Powershell task** or **RemoteDelete** task to delete the files.

For powershell task, there are many powershell script on the web to delete files from remote machine, like:

[Remote delete file with Powershell](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1788422-remote-delete-file-with-powershell)

For [RemoteDelete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=saeidbabaei.remotedeletesaeid) task, we need input your remote machine’s IP, username and password, there are also two options **Include Items** and **Exculde Items**.

Hope this helps.